# TeXstudio issue with dark theme in Catalina

Tags: texstudio, editors, mac

I updated to Catalina today and now my TeXstudio background is black. It looks nice sure, but whenever I click on a line, the line turns white and I cannot see what is written.

How do I turn the highlighting off, or turn the background white again?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferences, Syntax Highlighting, Line highlighting and then secondary click any box with a color to turn off the line highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

this unfortunately only solves the issue with one specific highlighting color. there are multiple problematic coloring/highlighting problems. e.g. black font on dark gray background etc

how to make texstudio use the normal light mode again? specifically without the "workaround" of switching to light mode in the OS itself

Comment: This... is not an answer...?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround on github (see https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/848#issuecomment-605485100):

> you can exclude texstudio from the mac os dark mode with the following command:
> `defaults write texstudio NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes`
> Command to reset this setting:
> `defaults delete texstudio NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance`